# Regular expression to match 10-15 and 20-26 and 30-40 characters in each line

Tags: regex

I'm new to regular expression and tried all possible things for past three days to dirty my hands but to no good.

I have a log file with multiple lines and each line as an event and I need to match fixed character length in the file.

Match 3-6 characters and 10-16 characters and 20-24 characters.

Sample event:

```
Ab FIN nm06feij act:ED1W Prcs:keansourcefile
```

I need to extract

`FIN`, `06feij` and `ED1W` fields.

Comment: "and tried all possible things for past three days to dirty my hands but to no good."  How about posting what you tried?  Also, a clearer specification of the problem is needed.

Comment: You need to post more samples for better understanding your log data structure.

Comment: A lot easier with `awk`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match using small slices and clever grouping:

```
sed -r 's/^.{3}(.{3}).{3}(.{6}).{5}(.{4}).*$/\1 \2 \3/g'
```

I tried using your only example and had exactly what you expected.

Comment: If extracting fixed columns is indeed what the OP is trying to ask about, regular expressions are not a particularly suitable tool for that.

Comment: I agree. But the OP asked regex, so regex it is :)